# Storyboard picked color differs from coded color

Tags: ios, xcode, colors, hex, rgb

I'm facing an unknown problem trying to use a color:

I have the color RGB: 0, 148, 216

If i use Xcode storyboard, i get a different color than using

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:148.0/255.0f blue:216.0/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How different are the colors?

Comment: The coded color is lighter - the storyboard color is darker. The alphas are the same

Comment: I think you are using different colorspec. Which section of the xcode color picker are you using? you are supposed to use RGB color spec as well in your IB

Comment: The more weird thing is that, the picker shows me the correct color, but assigns the wrong color, i ve noticed this capturing screen and using Fireworks color picker, it shows me the color applied is different that shown on Xcode Picker

Comment: The color picker has a pop-up for which device profile it's using. You can change it, directly below the magnifying glass icon in the system color picker. Is it set to "Device RGB"? If not, try that. If so, try the other options (particularly "Display") and see if that helps.

Comment: How do i close this as duplicate???